# Eexcelview Extension Does Not Work

Tags: php, yii

I have been trying to export CGridView data to excel or csv file and save the file. So, I used the the extension [EExcelView](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eexcelview/). As their instruction I extracted PHPExcel and EExcelView into extensions folder as ptrotected/PHPExcel and ptrotected/EExcelView and I wrote the following code into admin.php file as:

```
$this->widget('application.extensions.EExcelView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'autoWidth'=>true,
'exportType'=>'CSV',
'grid_mode' => 'export',
'filter'=>$model,
'filename'=>'newFile',
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    'email',
    'username',
    'password',
    'last_login_time',
    'create_time',
    'update_time',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
));
```

Unfortunately, I do not get any file to save rather I get that all the data are shown on browser. I applied several variation in option reading their instruction. But no luck. Please help me someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add stream option and set it to true, like this :

```php
$this->widget('application.extensions.EExcelView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'autoWidth'=>true,
    'exportType'=>'CSV',
    'grid_mode' => 'export',
    'stream'=>true, <----- ADD THIS LINE
    ...
```